# Form in a modal. Need to redirect to the modal after form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in a modal and after I submit the form, I want it to stay on the modal with new content.  So far, I have:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get">

        ${alert}
        <div class="spacing">&nbsp;</div>
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead><tr><th>#</th><th>Staff</th><th>Date</th><th>Project</th>  <th>Task</th><th>Notes</th><th>Hours</th></tr></thead>
        <c:forEach var="entry" items="${ref}" varStatus="count">
        <tr><td id="column1">${count.index+1}<td>${entry.staff}</td><td>${entry.date}</td><td>${entry.project}</td>
        <td>${entry.task}</td><td>${entry.notes}</td><td>${entry.hours}</td></tr>

    </c:forEach>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td id="total"></td></tr>

    </table>
    <input type='submit' value='EDIT' id='submitEdit'/>
</form>
```

and JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("#submitEdit").click(function(){
$("#dialog").modal('show');
//other code
```

The problem I am having is redirecting the page back to the modal after the form is being submitted.  Right now, it redirects back to the original page, not the modal.

Also, I tried the onsubmit event to call a javascript function, but that also did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this you're going to need to do a few steps:

1. Give your form an ID, my example uses `my_form`
2. Use AJAX to submit your form and send the response to the modal
3. Cancel the default action on the form.

**Example**

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#my_form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.get('/url/to/my/post/action', $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
        $('#dialog').html(response);
        $('#dialog').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want the submit to be a POST, not a GET?

Comment: @ryanulit One would think, but the OP's form method is GET, so I kept with what was there...  | __For clarification__, you can change `$.get` to `$.post` if you need to change the method.

Comment: Gotcha.  Missed that in his post.